# How to retrieve the text with beautifulsoup using python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to get the text that is repairsonwheelsrim-hub.com from the HTML using beautifulsoup pls let me know how I should do this. currently I'm using

```
webadress = profilePageSource.select("span#offscreen a[href]")[0].get_text()


<div class="biz-website">
<span class="offscreen">Business website</span>
<a target="_blank" href="/biz_redir?url=http%3A%2F%2Frepairsonwheelsrim-hub.com&src_bizid=8tY2YtXPk1rGO7sl43LH8A&cachebuster=1438073532&s=6b75d47d32b28eb8e50506859857b75e949d698cdbc47e9892cc2a3b43e480c2">repairsonwheelsrim-hub.com</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text='<div class="biz-website"> <span class="offscreen">Business website</span> <a target="_blank" href="/biz_redir?url=http%3A%2F%2Frepairsonwheelsrim-hub.com&src_bizid=8tY2YtXPk1rGO7sl43LH8A&cachebuster=1438073532&s=6b75d47d32b28eb8e50506859857b75e949d698cdbc47e9892cc2a3b43e480c2">repairsonwheelsrim-hub.com</a> </div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')    
print soup.a.text
```

**output:**

```
repairsonwheelsrim-hub.com
```

To loop through the text of the url:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text='<div class="biz-website"> <span class="offscreen">Business website</span> <a target="_blank" href="/biz_redir?url=http%3A%2F%2Frepairsonwheelsrim-hub.com&src_bizid=8tY2YtXPk1rGO7sl43LH8A&cachebuster=1438073532&s=6b75d47d32b28eb8e50506859857b75e949d698cdbc47e9892cc2a3b43e480c2">repairsonwheelsrim-hub.com</a> </div>'    
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')   
for t in soup.findAll("a"):
    print t.text
```

[For more on BS4 see their official site](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

**edit:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
a=requests.get("http://www.yelp.com/biz/scotts-pizza-tours-new-york")
text=a.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')   
for t in soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'a' and 'target' in tag.attrs):
    if "".join(t["target"]) in "_blank":
        print t.get_text()
```

**output:**

```
scottspizzatours.com
scottspizzatours.com
scottspizzatours.com/pri…
```

Comment: but how I can retrieve all the urls while looping.. the was the html field that will change on every page..

Comment: @NicoleW. the above will loop through all a tags and print them and if you want to search for new text you could just change `soup = BeautifulSoup(**your html text**, 'html.parser')` every time the html text changes

Comment: take a look on this url www.yelp.com/biz/repairs-on-wheels-brooklyn I want to collect the url of Repairs on Wheels pls let me know how I can using BS

Comment: http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&find_loc=NY&ns=1 see these business listings I can visit all the listings and append next pages

Comment: and this is the fist listing http://www.yelp.com/biz/scotts-pizza-tours-new-york I just want to collect this URL scottspizzatours.com

Comment: you want url or text ?

Comment: Nope I just want to collect the urls of the other websites

Comment: so you want to collect all the list url

Comment: Yep just the url of the businesses listed on yelp

Comment: Can be done but requires time will do tomorrow .In the mean time you see if it can be done

Comment: One hunch would be every `url ` are listed under `<h3 class="search-result-title">` 'h3 tag` tag so you can for loop over every `<h3 class="search-result-title">` tag and list the URL

Comment: @NicoleW. then what is your expected thing  I have done all that you asked for if this not helping post a new question with even more details stating what have you done and what you wnat with sample code